# FMDB Data insertions time

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, swift3, fmdb

In my app, I am thousands of records in each table. I have multiple table insertions. I am using fmdb. And for inserting data, I am using FMDatabaseQueue:

```
DBManager.GetQueue().inTransaction { (db, rollback) in
        var query: String = String()

        for obj in chatThreads
        {

            query += "insert or replace into \(TABLE_NAME) (\(COLUMN_THREAD_ID), \(COLUMN_CHAT_NAME), \(COLUMN_DATE_TIME)) values (\(obj.threadId), '\(obj.chat_name)', '\(obj.date_time)');"

        }

        if !(db.executeStatements(query)) {

        }
    }
```

I am inserting data, in the above mentioned way, to around 15 tables. 
Now, the problem is, FMDatabaseQueue inserts data one table after another, which is the way it is supposed to work. I am using FMDatabaseQueue for thread safety as I am inserting the data in the first two classes, and dont want any db lock issues to appear.

My question is, is there any way to make this a parallel process, so that I can insert data to different tables at the same time. If not, could you please direct me in correct path to achieve a better performance for the same. 
I have also tried batch insertions, but multiple insertions at the same time might cause db lock.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your own singleton class and method to insert data in table should return bool value to know data is been inserted or not.

If data is been stored in table then you can fire another method to insert data, ideally you can make chain to store data in table.

**Singleton class like this**

import Foundation
class LocalDatabase: NSObject {

```
//sharedInstance
static let sharedInstance = LocalDatabase()



    func methodToCreateDatabase() -> NSURL? {

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let urls = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)

    if let documentDirectory:NSURL = urls.first { // No use of as? NSURL because let urls returns array of NSURL

        // exclude cloud backup
        do {
            try documentDirectory.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
        } catch _{
            print("Failed to exclude backup")
        }

        // This is where the database should be in the documents directory
        let finalDatabaseURL = documentDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("contact.db")

        if finalDatabaseURL.checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError(nil) {
            // The file already exists, so just return the URL
            return finalDatabaseURL
        } else {
            // Copy the initial file from the application bundle to the documents directory
            if let bundleURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("contact", withExtension: "db") {

                do {
                    try fileManager.copyItemAtURL(bundleURL, toURL: finalDatabaseURL)
                } catch _ {
                    print("Couldn't copy file to final location!")
                }

            } else {
                print("Couldn't find initial database in the bundle!")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("Couldn't get documents directory!")
    }

    return nil
}

    func methodToInsertUpdateDeleteData(strQuery : String) -> Bool
    {

       // print("%@",String(methodToCreateDatabase()!.absoluteString))

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: String(methodToCreateDatabase()!.absoluteString) )

        if contactDB.open() {

            let insertSQL = strQuery

            let result = contactDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if !result {
                print("Failed to add contact")
                print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                return false
            } else {
                print("Contact Added")
                return true
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            return false
        }

    }

    func methodToSelectData(strQuery : String) -> NSMutableArray
    {

        let arryToReturn : NSMutableArray = []

        print("%@",String(methodToCreateDatabase()!.absoluteString))

        let contactDB = FMDatabase(path: String(methodToCreateDatabase()!.absoluteString) )

        if contactDB.open() {
            let querySQL = strQuery

            let results:FMResultSet? = contactDB.executeQuery(querySQL,
                withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            while results?.next() == true
            {
                arryToReturn.addObject(results!.resultDictionary())
            }

            // NSLog("%@", arryToReturn)

            if arryToReturn.count == 0
            {
                print("Record Not Found")

            }
            else
            {
                print("Record Found")

            }


            contactDB.close()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(contactDB.lastErrorMessage())")
        }

        return arryToReturn

    }
```

}

**And method to call from your viewcontroller like this**

```
if LocalDatabase.sharedInstance.methodToInsertUpdateDeleteData("INSERT INTO CONTACTS_TABLE (name, address, phone) VALUES ('Demo1', 'Demo2', 123)")
{
    NSLog("Store Successfully.")
}
else
{
    NSLog("Failled to store in database.")
}
```

**This is wrapper singleton class connected with FMDB**

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/SQLite_SingleManagerClass